# What does extern templates are a c++11 extension mean?

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, warnings, clang

When compiling crypto++ using XCode 4.2, I am receiving multiple warnings, all instances of "extern templates are a c++11 extension". What does this mean and would this affect the compatibility of the output executable?

Comment: Do some of the class template member function definitions lie in a separate implementation file (i.e. not within the header in which the class template is defined)?

Answer (score 5):

Declaring a template "extern" means that the compiler should *not* instantiate a given template in *this* translation unit, because it will be instantiated in another translation unit already. This is done to cut down on compile times.

This feature has been added with C++11, so a compiler not actually instructed to run in C++11 mode but aware of the issue might generate a warning like the one you are seeing.

Ref. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Extern_template).

Comment: Wait, so "extern templates are a c++11 extension" means extern templates are a c++11 extension???

Comment: @ta.speot.is: Yes, sometimes a compiler's error message means just what it says. ;-)